# :not(selector) isn't working properly

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Why is the code below is not working? It should hide all the elements that are not `p` but the `display` property isn't working properly.

```css
p {
  color: #000000;
}
 :not(p) {
  display: none;
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
 <h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Link to W3Schools!</a>
```

Comment: You have to specify: body :not(p)

Comment: Works as expected. Hides all the elements except `p`, including `p`'s ancestors.

Comment: @Oriol the code is having the correct behavior but not what OP is looking for ;)

Comment: @dippas Well, OP described what he expected, which seems to be the resulting behavior. They said it's not working correctly, without further details. Supposing that hiding `p`'s ancestors is undesired is just a guess. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior and a specific problem or error. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @Oriol well ya I understand you, but given the example and this `It should hide all the elements that are not p`  the answer can only be to given example right? :) I'm gonna add this to my answer

Answer (score 3):

Given your example and your request

> It should hide all the elements that are not `p`

You have to use `body :not(p)` - *which means you are using the `*` in the `not()` like this `body *:not(p)`*- so declaring that it will apply styles to all the children of the `body` except the `p`

```css
body *:not(p) {
  display: none;
  color: #f00;
}
p {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Link to W3Schools!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`div *:not(p) em {…}`

> This selects all em elements that are in an element (that is not a p element) and that are in a div element. so ***…*** is a match, but
>
> *…*
>
> is not.

Probably you should include the division. [My reference](https://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/)